# How can I use a callback method provided by a third-party native package in Flutter using a platform channel?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, flutter-method-channel

I'm trying to use a method provided by a third-party package in Flutter platform channe;.

So this is the Kotlin method

```
public final var logD: ((String?, String?, Int, String?) → Unit)?
```

Flutter MainActivity.kt

```
if (call.method == "getLogs") {
                //here i want to call the above method
            }
```

Comment: There are plenty of examples of Flutter method channel and plugins. Please update the question with more detail.